# How to browserify a browserified module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, commonjs

The title seems confusing but I'll give an example.

Let's say I create a module that uses ES6 that runs in the browser, so I use browserify with babelify to build everything.

Now I want to include that same module in a project that uses browserify, but does not uses Babel to compile ES6, so I need the compiled version.

I tried to require the "browserified" module like this:

```
// es5-project.js
require('./compiled-module-with-browserify');
```

But when I run `browserify es5-project.js` I start to get some errors like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module './XXX' from '/Users/mauricio.oliveira/projects/project-name/dist-folder'
```

And that makes sense, since browserify compiled all modules into one file, it won't find the modules inside the compiled file.

Does anyone have faced a problem like this one? if you did, how you solved it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

This will do the trick https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#browser-field

Just define a  "browser" index in the package.json file, and point to the initial source file.

:)

Comment: can you further explain on this? say i `require(pkg)` that doesn't work on client, but pkg.client works and its already browserified, how can i bundle that?

Comment: Sorry, can you give me some more details?

if `pkg.client` is already browserified, doesn't that mean that `pkg` is also?

If that's the case, in your `pkg` module, add the field `"browser": index.js` in the package.json, considering that index.js is the entry point for your `pkg` module.

`index.js` should be the `source` code, not the `dist` (browserified) code.